# How to enable ohasd.service using systemctl

Tags: systemd

RHEL 7.1 and Oracle 12c, I am not able to find what is wrong ? Please explain.

```
[root@lrma086 grid]# systemctl enable ohasd.service
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
[root@lrma086 grid]#  rpm -ql openssh-server | grep '\.service'
/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd-keygen.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd@.service
```

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118863/ for what this unit file probably contains.

Answer (score 2):

You could try add

[Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target

in the ohasd.service file, that would make the service autostart during the boot.

But may be this service is meant to be started as a dependency to another service, ant because of this the Install part is omitted?